# count no of spans of specific class within a dynamically generated div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Supposing I have a number of divs that are dynamically generated and contain text. Each of these divs have a unique id which is also dynamically generated, e.g.

```
<div id="abstract_12345"> ... text ...</div>
```

Now within those divs there are spans of a particular type that have been dynamically generated according to a regex, e.g. when the word "significant" is encountered it is tagged as

```
<span class="emphasis">significant</span>
```

This is being done via [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)

What would be a suggestion for a javascript function to enable counting the spans within each div with the aim of placing the count value in an element associated with that div?

Comment: @djsq: you suggested a css based solution - could you put that up again pls

Comment: What Yosvel Quintero posted is what i would also do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do:

```js
$('div[id^="abstract_"]').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this),
      len = $this.find('span.emphasis').length;

  console.log($this.attr('id'), len);
});
```

```css
div {margin: 0 0 15px 0;}
span.emphasis {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="abstract_12345"><span class="emphasis">Lorem ipsum</span> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <span>Sapiente ipsam animi</span>, alias harum aut est unde voluptates repudiandae vel molestias <span class="emphasis">significant</span>, officia! Illum dolore pariatur sequi magnam minus, aliquid voluptate officia, <span>quaerat</span> sint quam <span class="emphasis">commodi</span>.</div>

<div id="abstract_12346">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente ipsam animi, alias harum aut est unde voluptates repudiandae vel molestias, officia! Illum dolore pariatur sequi magnam minus, aliquid voluptate officia, <span>quaerat</span> sint <span class="emphasis">quam commodi</span>.</div>
```

Comment: Nope, OP said he has multiple divs with generated ids.

Comment: @dfsq Thanks for the comment. Updated the answer to count `span.emphasis` by `div`s with similar dynamic generated ids

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do using plain Javascript.

```
function myFunction() {
    var i;
    var x = document.querySelector("[id^=abstract_]").querySelectorAll("span");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length.i++){
        x[i].id = i;
    }
}
```

This code will add `id` to each `span` as the index of the `span` inside the div with `id=abstract_12345`.

Comment: OP said div id's are dynamically generated

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, if I understand your wish correctly.

```
$('id*="abstract_"').each(function() {
  var amount = $(this).find('span.emphasis').length;

  $(this).prepend(amount);
});
```